# Overload the assignment operator in C++

Tags: c++

I have a general question i C++ that I coudln't get a clear answer to and I'm hoping I get an answer to it here. As a programmer, do I need to explicitly overload the assignment operator for a class when all instance data fields in this class are standard built in C++ data types.

Comment: Someone might explain you the full details in an answer; but if a class only consists of primitive types, the default assignment operator will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You only need to overload the defaults if you are doing manual resource management.  If all of your members can be treated as [POD types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c) then you will be fine.

Answer (score -1):

No, you don't.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​